# ng-include for ion-view title

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to include a file as the 'title' of an `ionic-view`? I've been trying to resolve it to `'<span class="title" ng-include src="'+"./headerIcons.html"+'"></span>'`, but Ionic seems to be stripping out all the tags before it goes to the DOM. Am I missing something or is this not currently available?

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using the latest version and it works:

```
<ion-view hide-back-button="true" title="{{title}}">
```

and in my controller I have

```
$scope.title = '<img class="logo" src="img/logo.png"/>';
```

Hope it helps